# Unable to exclude directory using Get-ChildItem -Exclude parameter in Powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am using Powershell v 2.0. and copying files and directories from one location to another. I am using a string[] to filter out file types and also need to filter out a directory from being copied over. The files are being filtered out correctly, however, the directory I am trying to filter `obj` keeps being copied.

```
$exclude = @('*.cs', '*.csproj', '*.pdb', 'obj')
    $items = Get-ChildItem $parentPath -Recurse -Exclude $exclude
    foreach($item in $items)
    {
        $target = Join-Path $destinationPath $item.FullName.Substring($parentPath.length)
        if( -not( $item.PSIsContainer -and (Test-Path($target))))
        {
            Copy-Item -Path $item.FullName -Destination $target
        }
    }
```

I've tried various ways to filter it, `\obj`  or `*obj*`  or `\obj\`  but nothing seems to work.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/q/15294836/399704 for a similar question

Answer (score 57, accepted):

The `-Exclude` parameter is pretty broken. I would recommend you to filter directories that you don't want using `Where-Object (?{})`. For instance:

```
$exclude = @('*.cs', '*.csproj', '*.pdb')
$items = Get-ChildItem $parentPath -Recurse -Exclude $exclude | ?{ $_.fullname -notmatch "\\obj\\?" }
```

P.S.: Word of warning – don't even think about using `-Exclude` on `Copy-Item` itself.

Comment: Thanks! Worked like a charm!

Comment: If you're looking for a POSH 5.0 example or a way to handle multiple excludes, take a look at this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/35993562/615422

Comment: What is the role of "$_.fullname -notmatch '//obj//' here ? Sorry i am new to powershell wildcards.

Comment: Upvote for "The -Exclude parameter is pretty broken" because it is, and you're the first/only one who's diagnosed the problem.  Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

I use this to list files under a root but not include the directories

```
$files = gci 'C:\' -Recurse  | Where-Object{!($_.PSIsContainer)}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
Get-ChildItem -Path $SourcePath -File -Recurse | 
Where-Object { !($_.FullName).StartsWith($DestinationPath) }
```