# Get-ChildItem Recursive Exclude NOT Excluding Folder

Tags: powershell, get-childitem

I've check other posts and even following those I can't get this to function.

I'm trying to pull all of the ACL information from a drive but exclude the Windows folder.

This is the code I'm using, but it always tries to include the folder. Can someone tell me why this isn't working?

I've also tried `Where-Object`.

```psh
$containers = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Exclude $exclude |
              ? {$_.FullName -notmatch '\\windows\\?'}
```

Main Code:

```psh
function Get-PathPermissions {
    param ( [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)] [System.String]${Path} )

    begin {
        $root = Get-Item $Path 
        ($root | Get-Acl).Access |
            Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path" -Value $($root.fullname).ToString() -PassThru
    }
    process {
        $exclude = @('C:\Windows\*')
        $containers = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Exclude $exclude |
                      ? {$_.psIscontainer -eq $true}
        if ($containers -eq $null) {break}
            foreach ($container in $containers)
            {
            (Get-Acl $container.FullName).Access |
                ? { $_.IsInherited -eq $false } |
                Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Path" -Value $($container.fullname).ToString() -PassThru
            }

    }
}

Get-PathPermissions $args[0]
```

Comment: Try Get-ChildItem 'C:\*' -Exclude 'Windows'

Comment: Thanks but that doesn't seem to work either. The command line I enter is .\NTFSPermissions.ps1 "C:\" | Export-Csv C:\Permissions\output.csv -NoTypeInformation. Also tried Exclude 'Windows'

Comment: Try to invoke the script with \NTFSPermissions.ps1 "C:*" | Export-Csv C:\Permissions\output.csv -NoTypeInformation

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I did :) Still no luck. In fact that outputs a tiny file with path returned as System.Object[]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Unable to exclude directory using Get-ChildItem -Exclude parameter in Powershell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19842754/unable-to-exclude-directory-using-get-childitem-exclude-parameter-in-powershell)

Answer (score 3):

Filtering with `-notmatch '\\windows\\?'` should work. I'd use the full path, though, to avoid potential undesired exclusions:

```psh
$containers = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse |
              ? { $_.FullName -notmatch '^c:\\windows\\?' -and $_.PSIsContainer}
```

On PowerShell v3 or newer you can also use the `-Directory` switch for restricting the results to directories:

```psh
$containers = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse -Directory |
              ? { $_.FullName -notmatch '^c:\\windows\\?' }
```

Answer (score 3):

Couple points about the `-Exclude` parameter. While it does not explicitly mention it in the documentation it seems to work based on file and directory ***names***.... not the full paths themselves. As a result of that point it does not, in any way, work recursively with directories which I think is your actual conundrum.

Since `C:\Windows\*` is not a valid directory name that is why it is not filtering anything. [Jisaak](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1163423/jisaak)'s suggestion of changing `$exclude` to just "windows" did work in a sense. If you looked at your output you would have noticed that the actual "c:\windows" folder was missing. What you are actually having a problem with is that `exclude` does nothing for the sub folders of `C:\windows` which I will guess is what you intended.

There is [another SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19843156/3829407) about how `-Exclude` basically sucks. It can be useful as long as you understand its limitations. [Ansgar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30936140/3829407) covers the way around that. It will make sure nothing in the tree of `C:\windows` ends up in your results.