# Trying to Exclude a Folder with -Recursive search in get-childitem

Tags: powershell, search, recursion

I am new to PowerShell...

`SL D:\SomeFolder get-childitem -exclude <D:\Somefolder\A> -recurse -Directory`

I don't want `d:\somefolder\A` and its contents in the results, but for rest of the directories in "somefolder" I want recursive results.

I tried the command above, however, it is going inside the "\A" directory. It may be happening due to the `-recurse` switch, because if I don't use it...

Is there another way to achieve this?

Comment: "it may be happening due to recurse switch, coz if i dont use it... may be there is another way to achieve this" because if you don't use it ... what happens then? What should be on those dots?

Answer (score 3):

This lists children folders of D:\SomeFolder without D:\Somefolder\A:

```
get-childitem 'D:\SomeFolder' -recurse -Directory ` 
  | ? { $_.FullName -notlike 'D:\Somefolder\A*' }
```

See also [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294836/how-can-i-exclude-multiple-folders-using-get-childitem-exclude)