# Need some help on creating a script with PowerShell Get-ChildItem

Tags: windows, powershell

I've got a question. I want to do the following thing with PowerShell. Copy everything to a new directory except the folders named "56789" and "56789121". I tried `GCI` with the `-Exclude` option but it's not working as I want it.

You can find a visual representation of how I want to copy the things below:

```
C:\DATA
+---2
|   +---56789
|   +---Archived2001
|   |   |   66.txt
|   |   |
|   |   \---New folder
|   \---Archived2002
\---4
    |   33 - Copy.txt
    |   33.txt
    |
    +---56789121
    +---Archived2005
    \---Archived2008
            33 - Copy.txt
```

```
C:\MOVED
+---2
|   +---Archived2001
|   |   |   66.txt
|   |   |
|   |   \---New folder
|   \---Archived2002
\---4
    |   33 - Copy.txt
    |   33.txt
    |
    +---Archived2005
    \---Archived2008
            33 - Copy.txt
```

Until now I've got this but it's not working.

```cs
$from = 'c:\data'
$to = 'c:\moved'
$exclude = 'C:\data\*\[0-9]\'
Get-ChildItem -Path $from -r | ? {
    $_.PsIsContainer -and $_.FullName -notmatch '$exclude'
} | Copy-Item -Destination $to -WhatIf
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I exclude multiple folders using Get-ChildItem -exclude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294836/how-can-i-exclude-multiple-folders-using-get-childitem-exclude)

Comment: No code, no error message, hard to help. [You can edit your question to include these](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46295326/edit).

Comment: updated and added the code!

Comment: Your filter doesn't work because PowerShell doesn't expand variables in single-quoted strings. However, even with `'$exclude'` changed to `"$exclude"` your copy operation won't do what you want, because it doesn't preserve relative paths. You're looking for [`robocopy`](https://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/library/cc733145.aspx).

Comment: Tried `robocopy` but not working.
`robocopy C:\data C:\moved /lev:3 /xd 1* 2* 3* 4* 5* 6* 7* 8* 9* 0* /mir` this is the one I tried. I tried with different `/lev:n`

Comment: `robocopy C:\data C:\moved /xd 56789 56789121 ...`

Comment: yes this is working but for the specific folders. what If I have thousands of them? the structure is the same as the above mentioned

Comment: You build a list of the folders to exclude in a variable and use that: `robocopy ... /xd $excludes ...`.