# powershell script to get part of folder name with if statement

Tags: powershell

Hi As of acrobat drops support on x versions id like to make a script for our monitoring system.

Currently i have:

```
$FullFolderPath = 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe Reader DC';
$FolderName = (Split-Path $FullFolderPath -Leaf).ToString();
$DashIndex = $FolderName.IndexOf('Re');
$FolderNameFromDashToEnd = $FolderName.SubString($DashIndex);


$ADDC = "Reader DC"

if (($ADDC) -notcontains $FolderNameFromDashToEnd){
Write-Host "End of Support $adobeversion"
Exit 1010
}
else {
Write-Host "Adobe $FolderNameFromDashToEnd"
Exit 0
}
```

But i have both 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat 2017 and 
C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat Reader DC.

There are multiple version so i need to exclude all but reader dc folder.
Does anyone know a good hack for this?

Expect: If folder acrobat* excist but its not acrobat reader dc, then:

I also tried several options with:

```
$acrobatversion = Get-Childitem "C:\Program Files (x86)\Adobe\Acrobat*" | Select-Object @{Name="Name"; Expression = {$_.Name}}
$acrobatversion
```

But it just enlist the two acrobat folders

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I exclude multiple folders using Get-ChildItem -exclude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294836/how-can-i-exclude-multiple-folders-using-get-childitem-exclude)

Comment: Have you considered using the [System.IO] .Net class library with File or Directory?  Most Windows installations contain the libraries as part of the native OS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could check the [Uninstall registry keys](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa372105(v=vs.85).aspx) for information on the Reader installs. Then filter with `Where-Object` so that you only have Classic Track installs.

```
$ReaderClassicTrackInstalls = @((Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\), (Get-ChildItem HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\)) |
    ForEach-Object {
        Get-ItemProperty ($_ -replace 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE', 'HKLM:') |
            Where-Object {$_.displayname -like "Adobe Acrobat Reader*" -and $_.displayname -notlike '*DC'}
    }
$ReaderClassicTrackInstalls |
    Select-Object InstallLocation, DisplayVersion
```

Comment: thanks for sharing this with me, so cool that you guys can do this, im feel stupid maybe it time to follow a training

But the script didnt work no output while Acrobat Reader 2017 folder excist. Maybe its anothey key, will take a look tomorrow

Comment: Reader2017 does not follow the Uninstall registry keys method.  They have a lot of great documentation on their installers

Comment: @TheIncorrigible1 It's not a convention or a method. Both tracks of Reader installers are .msi based. The updates are .msp's. I just showed the output of a test install... It makes the reg key `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\WOW6432Node\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\{AC76BA86-7AD7-FFFF-7B44-AE1108756300}`...