# How to mapping a file by using path as filtering in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, file, mapping

I would like to mapping a file by using path as filtering.
I want to find file with extension .py, but not include in some specific path.
I've tried this way, but seems does not work.

```
$targetPath = "E:\TargetFolder"
$ignorePath = Get-Content -Path .\ignore_ls.txt

$getIgnoreList = Get-Content -Path .\ignore_ls.txt
foreach($list in $getIgnoreList){
    $mapping = Get-ChildItem -Path $targetPath\*.py -Recurse -Filter $list
    Write-Host "targetPath: $mapping"
}
```

Anyone can help me please. thank you so much

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I exclude multiple folders using Get-ChildItem -exclude?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294836/how-can-i-exclude-multiple-folders-using-get-childitem-exclude)

Comment: Sorry, I does not answer my question. I've checked it

Comment: So what does `ignore_ls.txt` contains? A list of full folder paths to exclude?

Comment: @zett42 yes, full folder path like `E:\FG1`